# MSBuild: How to conditionally import another project in a .csproj file based on the name of build-originated project?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, csproj, visual-studio-2022

Context: I have a .Net standard 2.0 project, say ProjectA in which I use an `<Import Project="xxxx.targets" />` statement to import a project from a target file. This solution has many projects (ProjectA, ProjectB, ProjectC and ProjectD). Project A is referenced in Project B and Project C using project references.

Here is the problem: If the build/rebuild request originated from a specific project, say ProjectC, I want to ignore this import statement and build the ProjectA normally. If the build request is originated from Project B or from Project A, I want to include this import.I understand that `<Import Project="xxxx.targets" />` can have a `"Condition"` attribute. But how do I implement this idea? Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The `ProjectReference` will cause a referenced project to be built if it is not already built. There is no support for changing the build of a referenced project based on the project that needs the project. And if you could that would create all sorts of issues. When building from the solution either ProjectB or ProjectC could trigger building ProjectA and, since ProjectA will be built once, it will be built 'incorrectly' for one of the projects.

For a given configuration/platform a project should always build the same.

But you can create new separate configurations.

For example:

1. In the default 'Release' and 'Debug' configurations, disable ProjectC.
2. Create new 'ProjectC-Release' and 'ProjectC-Debug' configurations.
3. In the 'ProjectC-Release|Debug' configurations, disable ProjectB.
4. In ProjectA (the project referenced by both ProjectC and ProjectB), conditionalize the `Import` based on the value of the `Configuration` property.

(However, I suspect that the question you have asked is not really the issue you are trying to solve.)